# Why RDS MySQL on 100% CPU is still responding?

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds

I sent an ALTER statement that took a long time and I killed some minutes after and then I noticed that CPU usage is almost 100% (98%, 99%, etc).

The process is still being listed with "Killed" status. Reading some answers here, I understand that a killed process can take a long time because it needs to do some rollbacks.

But I didn't get why the database is still running and responding to the application with almost 100% of CPU usage. There are some kind of prioritization on the database tasks?

Thanks

Comment: Do you only have one CPU core on your server? If it weren't a killed process but instead another process running a query simultaneously (or another application connection), would you still be surprised that those connections didn't block each other?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have 2 cores, you meant that the 100% CPU usage info on AWS refers to a single CPU? Tks!

Comment: When you have 2 cpu's in linux, they believe you have 200% available.  And you do since 1 cpu can be busy 100% and the other cpu can be busy 100%.

Comment: When you have the opportunity to use an 8 cpu in linux you could find 800% busy reported.

Comment: What was the `ALTER` statement?  Which version of MySQL?  Both can make a big difference in how to answer your question.

Comment: Also, what was the ALTER?  That makes a big difference.

Answer (score -1):

You can set below parameter value if you have 2 core cpu :

`innodb_thread_concurrency = CPU * 2`

Default value is 0, [A value of 0 (the default) is interpreted as infinite concurrency (no limit). This variable is intended for performance tuning on high concurrency systems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency)